# Error:Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, cors

I am doing api authentication using MERN stack...
**app.js** (server side)

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import routes from "./Routes/index.js";
import passport from "passport";
import jwt from "./config/passport.js";
import cors from "cors";
import User from "./Models/User.js";
import Todo from "./Models/Todo.js";

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/hello")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DB connection is successfull!");
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/api", routes);
passport.use("jwt", jwt);
app.use(cors({
  origin: "*"
}));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello world!!");
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running at http://localhost:4000");
});
```

**apiauth.js** (client side) from where i am requesting api response

```
import { requester } from "./baseapiurl";
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

export const SignUp=async(UserData,dispatch)=>{
    try {
        const res=await requester.post("/register",UserData);
        console.log(res);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

**baseapiurl.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
export const requester= axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:4000/api"
  });
```

while trying to request for register request , i got a error of cors though i have already implemented in backend side as above

**Full error:**:*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/api/register' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

**Anyone has idea behind this issue ? help me !!**

Comment: move `app.use(cors())` BEFORE attaching your api router ...

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to add

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

Comment: Setting the CORS headers on the request doesn't make any sense. They have to be set by the server on the response ...

Comment: Ok thank you, sorry for OP

Comment: @derpirscher can you help me for this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74121996/why-axios-interceptor-is-not-retrying-the-orginial-prevous-request-after-refresh